# docker run vs. docker-compose up: same image, different outcome

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

> **TL;DR** Using the same image, I get different results on running docker run and docker-compose up.

I am using the [official php docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/) and I want to install a set of extensions. Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:7.1.2-fpm

# Install software and dependencies (for extensions)
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -qy \
  libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
  libpng-dev \
  libicu-dev \
  mcrypt \
  libmcrypt-dev \
  libxml2-dev \
  libfreetype6-dev \
  libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
  libpng12-dev \
  git \
  nodejs

# Install required PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
    && docker-php-ext-enable gd

# Install and setup composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php \
  && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

# Cleanup tasks
RUN apt-get clean
```

As you see I am trying to install the `gd` library. This is actually taken from their example. On running `docker build` I see that it runs the configure and install steps (Step 3/5):

```
Step 1/5 : FROM php:7.1.2-fpm
 ---> 7191c638ed10
Step 2/5 : RUN apt-get update   && apt-get install -qy   libcurl4-gnutls-dev   libpng-dev   libicu-dev   mcrypt   libmcrypt-dev   libxml2-dev   libfreetype6-dev   libjpeg62-turbo-dev   libpng12-dev   git   nodejs
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1f53f9211603
Step 3/5 : RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/     && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd     && docker-php-ext-enable gd
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4598a07d9fca
Step 4/5 : RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php   && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
 ---> Running in 89c18c9ddf40
All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading...

Composer (version 1.4.0) successfully installed to: /var/www/html/composer.phar
Use it: php composer.phar

 ---> 059a1da3bb1a
Removing intermediate container 89c18c9ddf40
Step 5/5 : RUN apt-get clean
 ---> Running in 66c9cb68f684
 ---> f9543fa8b6e3
Removing intermediate container 66c9cb68f684
Successfully built f9543fa8b6e3
```

When I now do a plain `docker run` and ssh into the machine, the `gd` extension is available:

```
$ php -m
[PHP Modules]
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqlnd
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

Now, here is the interesting part: When I build (`docker build`) the image and then run the container with `docker-compose up`, the extension is not installed.

I narrowed it down to `docker-compose up` being the problem, as I did a lot of diffent things:

- `docker-compose build {servicename}` + `docker run {image-ID}` --> extension availabe
- removed all running containers and images, removed all docker-compose images (`docker-compose down`)

  - tried it with remote registry, using `dockerfile`, even building the image and then entering the local image in the `docker-compose.yml` --> same result

UPDATE

My `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:
  php:
      # this is the variant with the registry
      image: registry.example.com/devops/php:base-php-fpm
      volumes:
          - './src:/code'
          - './config/php:/usr/local/etc/php'
      links:
          - mysql
      depends_on:
          - mysql
  nginx:
      image: nginx:1.10
      ports:
          - "80:80"
      volumes:
        - './src:/code'
        - './config/nginx:/etc/nginx'
      depends_on:
          - php
      links:
          - php
  mysql:
      image: mysql
      ports:
          - "3306:3306"
```

Comment: COuld you add the docker-compose file?

Comment: is this image `registry.example.com/devops/php:base-php-fpm` built using the provided docker file?  and if so if you use docker run with this image whats the status of extension?

Comment: Yes, the registry image is build with the provided dockerfile. As stated above, I even build it locally and used it in the compose file to build with docker-compose. Docker run works, the extension is available. Only docker-compose up does not work.

Comment: Can you show your full `docker run` command too

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is the volume mount of the config file into the config folder of php - can only be found in my compose file. It overwrites the auto-generated config of PHP.

One of these things that keep you busy the whole day without delivering the tiniest piece of functionality...

Thanks for your help, guys!